# How do I alias a Homebrew installed Ruby 1.9 gem binary in /usr/local/bin?

Tags: macos, symbolic-link, ruby, homebrew, rubygems

Homebrew's Ruby 1.9 ships with rubygems. Doing `gem install ...` installs files and binaries into some long-winded path. For example, bundler is installed at:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/1.9.3-p0/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/bin/bundle
```

I'd like to have `gem` automatically symlink these binaries into a common location such as `/usr/local/bin` so that I don't have to manually link each of these binaries. Is this possible?

Answer (score 6):

Related question on StackOverflow: [Installing Ruby gems not working with Home Brew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138490/319266)

This little one-liner works perfect and is faster than querying brew-info:

```
export PATH=$(brew --prefix ruby)/bin:$PATH
```

More info in [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14138490/319266).

Comment: This works as advertised. Great!

Answer (score 5):

```
# Install 1 or more gems
gem install rails
gem install aws-sdk
# Then run these 2 commands to create bin links
brew unlink ruby
brew link ruby
# Finally open a new terminal session (no idea why but it worked for me)
```

Comment: Actually even if the gem bin doesn't autocomplete, you can type it, it's in the path. You don't have to restart a terminal session.

Comment: Homebrew no longer links ruby, as it refuses to shadow binaries provided by OS X.  You can put the ruby binary in your path, but it doesn't add binaries provided by gems.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up adding the following lines to .bashrc

```
RUBY_BINDIR=`brew info ruby|grep /bin|tr -d ' '`
export PATH=$RUBY_BINDIR:$PATH
```

The afore-mentioned brewbygems is not what you want, it's meant for the osx-builtin ruby and homebrew to play nice together, not if you installed ruby itself via homebrew.

Comment: This solved my problem of getting import failures for compass plugins during compiling a compass project, because it internally used macs builtin version of ruby.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me: [brewbygems](http://rgabostyle.com/2010/03/10/get-rid-of-sudo-instals-on-mac-os-x-with-homebrew-and-brewbygems.html)

I followed the instructions on that site, and installed the 'brewbygems' gem before (re)installing my ruby gems. As far as I can tell, brewbygems extends the gem system to make it aware of Homebrew. It then takes care of symlinking in the binaries when gems are installed.

Comment: Please add more information as to *why* this worked for you.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more detail. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

If you don’t want to touch your dot file, You can try:

```
brew unlink ruby && brew link ruby
```

New gems binaries symlinks will be created:

```
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0... 20 links removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.0.0-p0... 25 symlinks created
```